# React router - dynamic basename for built applications

Tags: reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

#### Situation

I am creating a backend library (e.g. java library or go module, etc, doesn't matter) which embeds a react application inside. The backend will expose handler endpoint that serves contents of `build` folder.
The goal of the library is to be part of the users application and the user should be able to attach it to any path they want. It can be simple root `/` or it can be some custom path, e.g. `https://users-site.com/my-custom-path`

Let's say that this library is "admin" panel which is accessible via `/admin` path or `/my-custom-path` in this case.

#### Problem

Location of the embedded library can be anywhere relative to the host.

Small snippet of application:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/my-custom-path">
      <Routes/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export const Routes = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Root}/>
        <Route path="/first/:param?" component={First}/>
        <Route path="/second/:param?" component={Second}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}

export const Root = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  return (
    <div>This is root
      <button onClick={() => history.push(`/first/some-param`)}>To First</button>
    </div>
  )
}

// First component is identiacal to Root component
      <button onClick={() => history.push(`/second`)}>To Second</button>

// Second component
      <button onClick={() => history.push(`/`)}>Back to root</button>
```

And `"homepage": "/my-custom-path",` in package.json

The problem is that in order for React Router to work I have to specify `basename` which should match the endpoint user decides to serve the library on, which is impossible to because basename has to be specified at build time.

Also `homepage` property has to be exact (cannot be relative, e.g. `"."` ) as in when browser refresh happens it loads static files relative to base location and not to current path

#### Solution

Currently the only solution I see is to hardcode the `basename` to some unique value and force all users of the library to have this mini-ui on this unique path of their application. (hardcoding root is not an option, as users might have other ui there)

Or ditch SPA and do some basic server side rendering, e.g. thymeleaf, go-templates, etc.

*Or maybe I am missing something out and it is doable?*

Comment: were you able to fix this?